# How to tackle finding sentences with the help of structures

Tags: first-order-logic

Assume a predicate logic language with binary predicate letter R and equality. Consider the following three models:

[image: Structures]

- Give a sentence $\varphi a$ that is true for 1, but not for 2 or 3.
- Give a sentence $\varphi b$ that is true for 3, but not for 1 or 2.
- Give a sentence $\varphi c$ that is true for 2, but not for 1 or 3.

My question is this: how can I find, or is there a good way to find, answers to these questions?

My thought process is as follows: I try to find any differences between the tree models. The only difference in this case that I can find is that between them, they differ in the number of relations they have. So, I think that I should base my answer on the number of relations, e.g. for the first model something like "There are exactly four relations". But then I'd have to write e.g. for 1: $\exists w \exists x \exists y \exists z ((wRx) \wedge (wRy) \wedge etc. \wedge \forall u(x = u \vee z = u...))$ That is going to be a very long formula!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unremarkable fact about (1) is that there is no point in it that 'sees' (R) every other point, so:

$$\phi_a\equiv \lnot\exists x \forall y(xRy).$$

The special feature of (3) is that it has a point (bottom left) that sees only one other point, so:

$$\phi_b\equiv \exists x\exists y(xRy \land \forall z(xRz \rightarrow z=y)).$$

Lastly, what's special about (2) is that it has two distinct points (top left, bottom right) s.t. every point either *is* or *is seen* by both of them (not sure if I expressed that properly). Formally that gives:

$$\phi_c \equiv \exists x \exists y(x \not= y \land \forall z([z=x \lor xRz] \land [z = y \lor yRz])).$$

Hagen's answer looks good. Mine are slightly different from his, so I thought I'd share the process.

Comment: Thanks, Hunan, for answering once again. I wish I was at least a bit good in this.  Simply amazing :-) Oh, I do have a question though; I noticed that Hagens' answer for (3) makes use of two universal quantifiers, whereas you have one. I keep reading his answer as "There is a node that has all other nodes as neighbours".

Comment: Another question! In your answer for (3), should there be a $x \neq y$?

Comment: Np Garth. My (3) says that the structure has a point (x) s.t. there is a point (y) that x sees (xRy), and everything (z) x sees (xRz) is that same point y. The $x \not= y$ is not required here. Hagen's answer is more natural: it says, there is a point (x) s.t. any two points (y,z) it sees (xRy and xRz) are identical. I'm not sure if that clears things up.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi :)

Answer (score 1):

Length should not be a problem (also, model 3 also has exactly four arrows). Of course, we will always start from a rather short *conceptual* formula and then translate it to the basics, which we should expect to produce somwhat longer formulas.

Instead of counting the total number of arrows, I'd suggest other (high-level) properties, such as

1. All nodes have at most two neighbours (i.e. among three neighbours, some must be equal)
   $$\forall x\forall y\forall z\forall w\colon (xRy\land xRz\land xRw)\to (y=z\lor y=w\lor z=w) $$
2. There exist at least two nodes having all others as neighbours
   $$\exists x\exists y\forall z\colon (x\ne z\to xRz)\land(y\ne z\to yRz)\land x\ne y$$
3. There exists a node with only one neighbor
   $$\exists x\forall y\forall z\colon (xRy\land xRz)\to y=z $$

There are of course other properties one can think of.
For example, do you see in which of the models
$$ \forall x\forall y\forall z\colon\neg(xRy\land yRz\land zRx)$$
holds?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I can't tell for sure. My feeling says it must be either 1 or 3.